# Immutable ConfigurationProperties from Bean Methods

Tags: java, spring

You can create `ConfigurationProperties`-Objects with Spring, in various ways.

One way, is to add the `@ConfigurationProperties`-Annotation to an `@Bean`-Declaration like so:

```
@Bean
@ConfigurationProperties("my.property.group")
public MyProperties myProperties() {
   return new MyProperties();
}
```

which will create a bean from `MyProperties`-class and consequently use its *setters* to fill its members with values from the configuration file.

You can also have the annotation directly on the `MyProperties`-Object like so:

```
@ConfigurationProperties("my.property.group")
public class MyProperties {
    @Getter @Setter private String myFirstValue;
    @Getter @Setter private String mySecondValue;
}
```

creating it by placing `@EnableConfigurationProperties(MyProperties.class)` to any loaded configuration.

It is also possible to create this class in an immutable way, using `@ConstructorBinding`

```
 @ConfigurationProperties("my.property.group")
 @ConstructorBinding
 public class MyProperties {
     @Getter private final String myFirstValue;
     @Getter private final String mySecondValue;
     
     public MyProperties(String myFirstValue, String mySecondValue) {
         this.myFirstValue = myFirstValue;
         this.mySecondValue = mySecondValue;
     }
 }
```

---

***But how can I create immutable ConfigurationProperties in combination with the first @Bean-method?***

I tried something like this:

```
 @Bean
 @ConfigurationProperties("my.property.group")
 // @ConstructorBinding <---- This is not applicable to methods
 public MyProperties myProperties(String myFirstValue, String mySecondValue) {
     return new MyProperties(myFirstValue, mySecondValue);
 }
```

which tells me, it could not autowire the parameters, I shall consider declaring some beans of type `String`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using Spring Boot 2.2.0's @ConstructorBinding for multiple Beans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58944506/using-spring-boot-2-2-0s-constructorbinding-for-multiple-beans)

Answer (score 0):

In the `Spring Boot` reference documentation for `@ConstructorBinding` it is said:

> To use constructor binding the class must be enabled using @EnableConfigurationProperties or configuration property scanning. You cannot use constructor binding with beans that are created by the regular Spring mechanisms (e.g. @Component beans, beans created via @Bean methods or beans loaded using @Import)

See [Spring boot documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html)

Perhaps some of the answers in [Immutable @ConfigurationProperties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26137932/immutable-configurationproperties) will be enough to solve your problem.

Comment: Thank you, Fatih! So far I got it already, as `@ConstructorBinding` has no `METHOD` in the `@Target`-List. And it would be strange, given the name, also. I'd rather have some `@BeanMethodBinding` or something like that.  Any clean way to create immutable `@ConfigurationProperties` via `@Bean`-Methods.

Comment: @derM Maybe the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26137932/immutable-configurationproperties) will help you a little bit for what you want to do.